# Timeout configuration for CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I am running CloudFormation updates to ECS. Triggered by CodePipeline. I would like to abort the CloudFormation deployment and rollback to the previous version after a timeout.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I saw something about WaitConditions but I'm not sure that is the right mechanism.

I also found that you can configure a `TimeoutInMinutes` on nested stacks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-timeoutinminutes - but sounds like you cannot apply a similar property at the top level of the stack or to an arbitrary resource?

Is there another way that I can use the combination where I can abort the Codepipeline->Cloudformation->ECS deployment after a few minutes if it doesn't succeed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general gripe with CodePipeline ECS Deploy action (ECS, not ECS B/G) that if you push a bad image, you will have to wait 1hr for the timeout to occur before you can retry the pipeline.

At the moment, CodePipeline doesn't support rollbacks. You can detect a failed pipeline using CloudWatch [1] and take some action. The action will probably be roll-forward to a good version.

[1] Detect and React to Changes in Pipeline State with Amazon CloudWatch Events  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html

Answer (score 0):

We don't use CodePipeline, we're using Sceptre. But I guess my workaround could still work.
My workaround for this problem is that before triggering a deployment, run a script in the background.

```
./deployment-breaker.sh &
```

And for the script

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 600
$deploymentStatus = (aws cloudformation describe-stack --stack-name STACK_NAME | jq XXX)
if [[ $deploymentStatus == YOUR_TERMINATE_CONDITION ]]then
  aws cloudformation cancel-update-stack --stack-name STACK_NAME
fi
```